# Selecting binaries for respective architectures

Tags: android, android-ndk, processors, precompiled-binaries

I am having executable binaries(not shared lib) for following architectures:

- *arm64-v8a*
- *armeabi*
- *armeabi-v7a*
- *mips*
- *mips64*
- *x86*
- *x86_64*

Now do i need to put all these binaries to my apk(will cost me 300kb),or some binaries can run on multiple architecture??
Please suggest me which can run on which processors.

Comment: armeabi, mips, and mips64 are deprecated in NDK r16 and will be removed in NDK r17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than 99% of the android devices can run executables build for *armeabi-v7*.

So as of now i am only including this one binary.

Comment: Starting sometime in 2019 you will be required to include 64-bit versions of all your native libraries (i.e. if you include a library for armeabi-v7a you will be required to also include one for arm64-v8a).